# Поиск значений по клиентам в разрезе дат в Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Друзья, всем привет!

Прошу помочь в решении следующего вопроса. Важно(!): решение прошу адаптировать для Excel 2010.

У меня имеется таблица порядка 1600 строк. Вот краткий пример:

| Дата | ФИО | Сумма |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.02.2023 | Петрова | 10 |
| 03.02.2023 | Петрова | 11 |
| 04.05.2023 | Жукова | 20 |
| 04.07.2023 | Жукова | 22 |
| 05.06.2023 | Жукова | 33 |
| 01.01.2023 | Ельцина | 13 |
| 01.02.2023 | Ельцина | 14 |
| 03.04.2023 | Зверев | 12 |
| 05.06.2023 | Зверев | 13 |
| 05.05.2023 | Зверев | 14 |
| 06.10.2023 | Зверев | 15 |

В таблице представлены ФИО клиентов, даты и суммы их платежей. Как видно из данных, даты по клиентам могут идти "вразнобой", но фамилии клиентов всегда идут подряд, т.е., например, Петровой не окажется в конце датафрейма.
Задача состоит в том, чтобы напротив Фамилии, которая встречается в таблице более 2-ух раз указать сумму платежа по наиболее поздним датам, т.е. должно получиться следующее:

| Дата | ФИО | Сумма | Расчетный столбец |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.02.2023 | Петрова | 10 |  |
| 03.02.2023 | Петрова | 11 |  |
| 04.05.2023 | Жукова | 20 |  |
| 04.07.2023 | Жукова | 22 | 22 |
| 05.06.2023 | Жукова | 33 |  |
| 01.01.2023 | Ельцина | 13 |  |
| 01.02.2023 | Ельцина | 14 |  |
| 03.04.2023 | Зверев | 12 |  |
| 05.06.2023 | Зверев | 13 | 13 |
| 05.05.2023 | Зверев | 14 |  |
| 06.10.2023 | Зверев | 15 | 15 |

Пока не представляю как скооперировать стандартные функции Excel для получения расчетного столбца.
Прошу оказать помощь в решении такой задачи. Пробовал обращаться к Chat GPT, но решение предложенное им не подошло:

=ЕСЛИ(СЧЕТЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$12, $B2) > 2, ЕСЛИ($A2 = МАКС(ЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$12 = $B2, ЕСЛИ($A$2:$A$12 > $A2, $A$2:$A$12)))), $C$2:$C$12), C2, ""), "")

Формулу выполнять, по уверению Бота нужно через CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расчетный столбец - *D*. В *D2* вписать формулу

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$12;B2)>2;И(A2<>НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(ЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$12=B2;$A$2:$A$12);{1;2}))*C2;)
```

Т.к. это формула массива, ее ввод завершить комбинацией клавиш *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. (формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками). Копировать ячейку вниз.

Для этой формулы неважен порядок дат, фамилии тоже могут быть перемешаны.

Eсли у одного плательщика вторая из меньших дат будет иметь повтор (плательщик платил несколько раз в один день), то значение в расчетный столбец не подставится.

Но если отсортировать не фамилии, а даты (по возрастанию), то формула будет простая и очень быстрая:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($B$2:B2;B2)>2;C2;)
```

Comment: Я бы завершил первую формулу не "C2;)", а "C2;"")", чтобы она не выводила нули. И её не нужно вводить как формулу массива, она и так работает.

Comment: А ещё лучше её сделать такой: =ЕСЛИ(И(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$12;B2)>2;A2<>НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(ЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$12=B2;$A$2:$A$12);{1;2}));C2;"")

Comment: Все это неправильно :) ===Данные в диапазон должны выводиться в одинаковом формате. "" - это текст, строка нулевой длины. Текст среди чисел - мина замедленного действия, может навредить при дальнейших вычислениях. Можно, конечно, если диапазон не предполагается использовать в вычислениях, но лучше привыкать размещать данные правильно

Comment: Согласен. Ну тогда можно просто отключить отображение нулей.

Comment: === Пишем формулу `=НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(ЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$12=B2;$A$2:$A$12);{1;2})` Не выходя из режима редактирования, нажимаем `F9`  - в ячейке видим массив из двух значений. Но после выхода из ячейки в ней отображается только одно значение - первое из массива. И если массив дополнительно не обработать и не ввести как формулу массива, для вычислений будет взято только это значение. Поэтому дополнительно функция `И` и формула массива. === Незначащие нули можно скрыть: *Файл-Параметры-Дополнительно-Параметры для листа*, снять галку *Показывать нули*...

Comment: Вот тут немного неправильно вы рассуждаете. Действительно, "=НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(...)" возвращает массив, но этот массив у вас редуцируется функцией И, а вся формула выводит единственное значение и поэтому не нуждается в выводе массивом. Это лекго проверить - просто не вводить как формулу массива - результат будет тот же самый. С предлагаемым мной изменением результат будет такой же, так как массив всё так же будет редуцироваться фукцией И, а И в данном случае походит для объединения двух "<>" вместе с первым аргументом.

Comment: Ввод формулы как формулы массива влияет только на вывод результата этой формулы, но не влияет на вычисления внутри формулы.

Comment: Благодарю вас ребят за помощь! **Все получилось.**

Comment: И, кстати, поскольку мы и так отбрасываем две наименьшие даты, формулу можно упростить: =ЕСЛИ(И(A2<>НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(ЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$12=B2;$A$2:$A$12);{1;2}));C2;"")

Comment: @rotabor, ни в коем случае! Во-первых, условие обрезает лишние вычисления (у плательщиков с оплатами <3 шт.). На больших диапазонах это существенное ускорение вычислений. Во-вторых, формула без условия вернет ошибку в строках плательщиков, у которых только один платеж.
Перенос  условия со `СЧЕТЕСЛИ`  в тело функции `И` ведет к этой же ошибке, а еще добавляет вычислений.
О формулах массива рассуждения тоже ошибочны. Массив, создаваемый в теле НАИМЕНЬШИЙ`` функцией `ЕСЛИ`, обязует вводить формулу как формулу массива. Добавил ответ с демонстрацией ошибок.

Comment: Согласен с лишними вычислениями и ошибкой с одним платежём. По формуле массива - у меня другой результат. Вы на 2010 проверяете? Поместил картинку в ваш ответ, иначе не придумал как.

Comment: Да, 2010. Excel 365 моложе, там новшеств больше

Answer (score 1):

О формулах массива

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разберем формулу в `F4` (формула массива)

Функция `ЕСЛИ` (в теле `НАИМЕНЬШИЙ`) вернет массив `{ЛОЖЬ:ЛОЖЬ:45050:45111:45082:ЛОЖЬ:ЛОЖЬ:ЛОЖЬ:ЛОЖЬ:ЛОЖЬ:ЛОЖЬ}`

Функция `НАИМЕНЬШИЙ` игнорирует логические выражения, работает с числами (числа в массиве - это числовой формат дат) и вернет два значения: `45050` (04.05.2023) и `45082` (05.06.2023)
При сравнении на неравенство `А4` с этим массивом получаем новый массив: `{ЛОЖЬ;ИСТИНА}`

`СЧЁТЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$12;B4)>2` - вернет `ЛОЖЬ`

Промежуточный результат вычислений: `И(ИСТИНА;{ЛОЖЬ;ИСТИНА})`

Далее: `И(ИСТИНА;{ЛОЖЬ;ИСТИНА})` => `И({ЛОЖЬ;ИСТИНА})` => `ЛОЖЬ`

Т.е. в результате в ячейку `F4` сумма из `С4` не выводится. Но если формула введена без "трьохпальцевого ввода" (ячейка `Е4`), видим ошибочное отображение суммы. Почему? Виной всему игнорирование того, что функция `ЕСЛИ` формирует массив.

Обратите внимание на четыре правых столбца таблицы. Из массива извлекаются минимальное и максимальное число, т.е. фактически показываем два значения, полученные функцией `НАИМЕНЬШИЙ`. Разница только в том, что в `I:J` формула обычная, а в `K:L` введена как формула массива.

rotabor

Excel 365 - в колонках E, I и J результатs отличаются:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Связано с версией?

После внимательного анализа прихожу к выводу, что массив таки возвращается фунцией `ЕСЛИ` (в теле `НАИМЕНЬШИЙ`), так как потом из результата функции `НАИМЕНЬШИЙ` можно получить два значения, которые и показаны в колонках I и J. Проблему вижу в другом - не работает часть '$B$2:$B$12=B2' в `ЕСЛИ`.

vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA

Еще интересности: в ячейке отображаемое значение зависит от номера строки диапазона:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

rotabor

Получается, что "ЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$12=B2;$A$2:$A$12)" просто выдаёт весь массив "$A$2:$A$12", а извлекается из него элемент по положению ячейки формулы относительно начала массива.

vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA

Объяснение простое. При массивном вводе формула четко видит, что нужно работать с массивом. Без массивного ввода (мы уже знаем, что есть зависимость от номера строки диапазона) - для сравнения берется плательщик из текущей строки:

```
строка 2 (№1 диапазона) - ЕСЛИ($B$2=B2;$A$2:$A$12)
строка 3 (№2 диапазона) - ЕСЛИ($B$3=B3;$A$2:$A$12)
строка 4 (№3 диапазона) - ЕСЛИ($B$4=B4;$A$2:$A$12)
```

Т.е. в каждой строке условие истинно, поэтому возвращается диапазон $A$2:$A$12.

В Excel-2010 есть функции, которые формируют массив, не требуя при этом массивного ввода. Вариант решения задачи немассивной формулой:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$12;B2)>2;И(A2<>НАИБОЛЬШИЙ(МУМНОЖ(($B$2:$B$12=B2)*$A$2:$A$12;1);СЧЁТЕСЛИ($B$2:$B$12;B2)-{1;0}))*C2;)
```

На самом деле такая формула кушает больше ресурсов, чем формула массива, показанная в ответе - `МУМНОЖ` прожорлива.

Comment: По поводу колонок I и J. У вас какие-то странные результаты. [I2]="01.01.2023" - такого значения вообще нет во входных данных для Петровой.

Comment: Но есть в диапазоне. О чем я и твержу - такие массивы обрабатываются формулами массива (2010). Без этого выдают ошибки

Comment: А по поводу этого: *Но после выхода из ячейки в ней отображается только одно значение - первое из массива* - нужное уточнение: для этой строки.  В следующей строке будет отображено второе значение массива, дальше - третье, четвертое... См. картинку в нашем общем ответе

Comment: Сделал один интересный вывод: "После внимательного анализа ..."

Comment: В общем, это какая-то хитрая особенность, которая пока непонятна. Возможно, как-то можно модифицировать '$B$2:$B$12=B2', что бы получить нужный результат, но у меня это проверить негде. Не уверен, что этим стоит заниматься.

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Думаю, теперь все стало на свои места )